# How to select options from array with form_tag and checkboxes

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array `@sources` that contains names (strings) of sources. In a view I want to list every source with a checkbox in a remote form. Then in the linked controller action I would like to have an array in the params hash, containing only those sources, that the user has checked before submitting.

I tried doing that manually, like so:

```
<%= form_tag select_sources_user_wordsearch_path(@user, @wordsearch), {method: :post, remote: true} do %>
  <% @sources.each do |source| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="pull-left">
          <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right"> <%=source%>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit_tag "Start Search",id:"search_commit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But when submitting the form, I don't even see a params hash:

```
Started POST "/users/1/wordsearches/77/select_sources" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-15 16:18:06 +0200
Processing by WordsearchesController#select_sources as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Start Search", "user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"77"}
```

So I was looking around to see what's going on with the `form_tag` helper and `check_box_tag`. And in check_box_tag's [API page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag#64-Pass-id-collections-with-check-box-tags) (see comments) I found that it is possible to pass a collection into it and receive the result of the selection in an array in the params hash. Basically, what I described above.

I am wondering how this would be done inside a `form_tag` for a remote form, with an array (instead of a collection)?

In the `form_tag` [API page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) I couldn't find anything about how the data is transferred to the controller. In the check_box_tag there is nothing mentioned about how to handle collections.

Can anyone tell me how this is done "the Rails way"?
It has to be easier than I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: why don't you use the the `form_for` helper? Could be something like `form_for @wordsearch, url: select_sources_user_wordsearch_path(@user, @wordsearch), {method: :post, remote: true} do`.

You may also have a look at the `collection_check_boxes` helper in [the API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes).

Afaik this can only be used with `form_for` and the corresponding form object.

```
<%= form_for @wordsearch do |form| %>
  <%= form.collection_check_boxes(:source_ids, @sources, :id, :labeling_method ) %>
<% end %>
```

Assuming `@sources` is some kind of an object. In your case

```
<%= form_for @wordsearch do |form| %>
  <%= form.collection_check_boxes(:sources, @sources, :to_s, :to_s ) %>
<% end %>
```

could work as well. (Did not try it!)

Another way would be to just send the values manually like so:

```
<% @sources.each do |source| -%>
   <%= check_box_tag "wordsearch[sources][]", source -%>
   <%= source -%>
<% end -%>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try those approaches.